# use vlookup to return multiple values and expand rows

Tags: database, excel, vlookup, inventory, invoice

I am trying to create a semi-automated invoicing system for my business but I am running into some problems.

I would like to be able to have a spreadsheet with all of my inventory in rows. Each of these items would have 4-5 columns of information. I would like to use this spreadsheet as a database that I could use data validation with to create a drop down menu to choose an item from the database. When an item is selected it would return all of the columns of info in the database.

I have been able to do this using vlookup functions. However, most of the items in my database are often grouped together. Is there a way that I could select one item from the database and have it return all of the grouped items on separate rows?

Lastly, as these items are added to the invoice it would be nice if I could automatically have the invoice add rows to expand the invoice. For example, if I choose an item from my database that is grouped with 10 other items, the spreadsheet would also add 10 rows or shift the rows below the dropdown selection down 10 rows.

From my research I have figured out how to return multiple values from an array following the instructions on this link:
https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/10/25/how-to-return-multiple-values-using-vlookup-in-excel/

This only allows me to return a single value though.

Here is a link to the excel file in case you don't want to sift through the entire page:
https://www.get-digital-help.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/How-to-return-multiple-values-vertically-2.xlsx

I also followed this guide to use a vlookup function to return multiple values but I don't know how to have it return multiple items from the database.

https://www.journalofaccountancy.com/issues/2004/apr/adoityourselfautomatedinvoicingsystem.html

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's time you left VLOOKUP behind, and embraced PivotTables. Slicing, dicing, and aggregations are what they do best, and they handle grouped items with ease. Trying to cobble together a solution that meets your requirements using just formulas is going to be messy.

Comment: Ah! This sounds like exactly what I need. I will do some research on my own so I can better understand pivot tables but I would really appreciate your help if you can put something basic together I can expand on.